# Regex for matching URL with no extension and with specific word in it

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm receiving a URL like this: `http://blog.test.com/post/2017/1/testpost-blog-January`

I want to make a Regex pattern that matches an URL with **no** extension and with the word **post** in it.

**[Examples]**

`http://blog.test.com/post/2017/1/testpost-blog-January`  -> match

`http://blog.test.com/post/2017/1/testpost-blog-January.aspx` -> no match

`http://blog.test.com/Testpage.aspx` -> no match

What I've tried so far:

```
(?=.*^([^.]+)$)(?=.*post)
```

This is not working somehow.

Do you have any idea how to rewrite my pattern correctly?

Thx :)

Comment: Try `^(?=.*post)(?!.*\.[^/.]+$).*`

Comment: Kinda right, I just had to escape the forward slash: ^(?=.*post)(?!.*\.[^\/.]+$).*  Thank you

Comment: In ASP.NET, you do not have to escape the `/`, it is only required if you are using the pattern inside `/` regex delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the lookaheads like this:

```
^(?=.*post)(?!.*\.[^\/.]+$).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmGUOY/1) (in the demo, `\n` is added to the negated character class since it is a multiline demo.)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*post)` - a positive lookahead requiring the string to have a `post` literal char sequence inside after any 0+ chars
- `(?!.*\.[^\/.]+$)` -  a negative lookahead that will fail the match if after any 0+ chars there is a dot followed with 1+ chars other than `/` and `.` up to the end of string
- `.*` - matching pattern getting the whole line.